# soap query with php and wsdl to get result

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm having trouble finding a good example of how to do a soap call with a wsdl in php.

I found this example, but it's tied to the google function:

[doGoogleSearch](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch12_09.htm)

```
$hits = $soap->doGoogleSearch('your google key',$query,0,10,
                               true,'',false,'lang_en','','');
```

I found this example for a wsdl, but I'm not seeing where my query goes:

[missingQuery](https://github.com/phpro/soap-client/blob/master/docs/wsdl-providers.md)

So basically, this is what I have so far, but there's a lot missing:

```
$wsdlDB = "htmlString?wsdl";
// xml string for login and query I know works in soapUI with $var
    $query = "$query = 
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tri="http://blah/dbOurs/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tri:sendTransaction>
        <loginName>unernm</loginName>
         <loginPassword>pw</loginPassword>
                ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'

$result = "not sure where this ties in either";

$WSDL = new SOAP_WSDL($wsdlDB);
$soap = $WSDL->getProxy();

$hits = $soap->($query, $result);
```

//then I will extract $varAnswer from $result with regex probably

This is really unclear.  Does anyone have any helpful info on how to submit the query to the DB with the WSDL?  I shouldn't have to give the soap call a specific function to do the query with.  It's supposed to get that from the wsdl definition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php). It will convert the input to the function into a Soap Message and extract the return message into an object; based on the WSDL.

A simple sample is shown below.

```
$blzCode = '10010424'; // Code to lookup
$wsdlDB = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl"; // WSDL URL
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlDB); // Create the client based on the WSDL
$returnValue = $client->GetBank(array('blz' => $blzCode)); // Pass in the Parameters to the call (Based on the WSDL's definition)
$bankDetails = $returnValue->details; // Extract the results
$bankName = $bankDetails->bezeichnung; // Extract some portion of the inner result
echo "Blz Code {$blzCode}'s bank name is {$bankName}" . PHP_EOL; // Do something with the data
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the GetBank is, or what the array parameters are referring to.

Comment: I added info on the query/connection that I use.  I'm not sure how to apply that to what you're showing.

Comment: @Michele, Did you look up the WSDL for the BLZService, you should see the GetBank call there.